# How to solve AggregateException?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api2

I got AggregateException like this in my Web-API:

> {
>         "Message": "An error has occurred.",
>         "ExceptionMessage": "One or more errors occurred.",
>         "ExceptionType": "System.AggregateException",
>         "StackTrace": "   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean
>   includeTaskCanceledExceptions)\r\n   at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean
>   waitCompletionNotification)\r\n   at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()\r\n   at
>   CapstoneAPI.Controllers.LitigantsController.PostLitigantAndImage(LitigantUpdateReq
>   litigant) in E:\SE1166\Spring
>   2019\SWP\capstone\CapstoneAPI\CapstoneAPI\Controllers\LitigantsController.cs:line
>   207\r\n   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.b__9(Object
>   instance, Object[] methodParameters)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object
>   instance, Object[] arguments)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location
>   where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()",
>         "InnerException": {
>           "Message": "An error has occurred.",
>           "ExceptionMessage": "Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path '', line 1, position 1.",
>           "ExceptionType": "Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException",
>           "StackTrace": "   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadStringValue(ReadType readType)\r\n 
>   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadAsString()\r\n   at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader.ReadForType(JsonContract contract, Boolean
>   hasConverter)\r\n   at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader
>   reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)\r\n   at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader,
>   Type objectType)\r\n   at
>   System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.ReadFromStream(Type
>   type, Stream readStream, Encoding effectiveEncoding, IFormatterLogger
>   formatterLogger)\r\n   at
>   System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonMediaTypeFormatter.ReadFromStream(Type
>   type, Stream readStream, Encoding effectiveEncoding, IFormatterLogger
>   formatterLogger)\r\n   at
>   System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.ReadFromStream(Type
>   type, Stream readStream, HttpContent content, IFormatterLogger
>   formatterLogger)\r\n   at
>   System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.ReadFromStreamAsync(Type
>   type, Stream readStream, HttpContent content, IFormatterLogger
>   formatterLogger)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location
>   where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Net.Http.HttpContentExtensions.<ReadAsAsyncCore>d__0`1.MoveNext()"
>         }
>       }

And this is the function where I got the error:

```
public IHttpActionResult PostLitigantAndImage (LitigantUpdateReq litigant)
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:56524");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            Litigant _litigant = new Litigant
            {
                ID = litigant.LitigantId,
                Name = litigant.Name,
                Nation = litigant.Nation,
                Sex = litigant.Sex,
                Address = litigant.Address,
                DoB = litigant.DoB,
                HomeTown = litigant.HomeTown,
                IdentifyCard = litigant.IdentifyCard,
                PortraitImage = litigant.PortraitImage
            };
            var rcontent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_litigant);
            var buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(rcontent);
            var content = new ByteArrayContent(buffer);
            HttpResponseMessage response1 = client.PostAsync("api/Litigants", content).Result;
            content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json");
            LitigantImage image = new LitigantImage
            {
                ID = litigant.LitigantImageId,
                Link = litigant.Link,
                LitigantID = litigant.LitigantId
            };
            rcontent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(image);
            buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(rcontent);
            content = new ByteArrayContent(buffer);            
            HttpResponseMessage response2 = client.PostAsync("api/LitigantImages", content).Result;
            if(response1.StatusCode.Equals(HttpStatusCode.Created) && response2.StatusCode.Equals(HttpStatusCode.Created))
            {
                return Content(HttpStatusCode.Created, litigant);
            }
            else
            {
                if (!response1.StatusCode.Equals(HttpStatusCode.Created))
                {
                    return Content(response1.StatusCode, "Error in update class Litigant! Error: \n" + response1.Content.ReadAsAsync<string>().Result);
                    //return Content(response1.StatusCode, "Error in update class Litigant!"); 
                }
                else
                {
                    return Content(response2.StatusCode, "Error in update class LitigantImage! Error: \n" + response1.Content.ReadAsAsync<string>().Result);
                    //return Content(response2.StatusCode, "Error in update class LitigantImage!");
                }
            }
        }
```

So, how can I figure where cause the error in my code? Moreover, which is the best way to solve the error?

*The class call 2 other post api but when I test the post apis, they run normally and don't get the error. I think it in I set up the content to post to the api but I don't know the way to fix that.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to parse invalid JSON, try and debug your program

Comment: I use the post api so create data on database so in the above code, which line that make the code try to parse invalid JSON? :/

Comment: check LitigantsController.cs:line 207

Comment: Now the line is 216 and it is: 
return Content(response2.StatusCode, "Error in update class LitigantImage! Error: \n" + response1.Content.ReadAsAsync<string>().Result);
and I still dont know how it cause error :/